# 2 Sliding Divs horizontally Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slide

I want to make something like [this.](http://www.zaption.com/tours/54fcf5bbace575ba19e9181e)

Where a container slides out at a certain point. The way I imagine it would be of 2 divs. 1 front and 1 back. And the whole container is still centralized when both divs are out.

I am not sure how do I even start. Possible to get some guide to start off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing this. Please note that I am using CSS transition property, which is not supported in IE below 9 and older versions of other browsers.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".container").toggleClass("opened");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transition: margin-left .2s linear;
}

.container.opened {
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.back {
  background: red;
  transition: margin-left .2s linear;
}

.container.opened .back {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.front {
  background: green;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="front"></div>
</div>
<button type="button">Push me!</button>
```

Another way is to use jQuery Animate instead of adding class `open` to the `div.back`:

```
$( ".back" ).animate({
    margin-left: 200px,
}, 200,
function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

Comment: That looks good but I will need the container div to be centralized as well when .back is opened. I think I might know how to work around this. Thanks Tim!

Comment: I've edited my code according to your comment. Please feel free to mark my answer as accepted :)